# Как запустить рендер в 3d max на сервере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 3d, blender, 3dsmax

Имеется серваки с мощными gpu, на них рендерим сцены. ОС ubuntu 14.04.
Раньше работали с блендером, то есть получали от дизайнеров файл .blend, потом закидывали на сервак и запускали рендеринг. 
Команда, которой это делалось раньше:

```
blender scene.blend --engine CYCLES -t 0 -b --render-output //results/
```

Сейчас дизайнеры переехали на 3d max. Какие действия нужны для того, чтобы так же после получения файлов .max (честно говоря не знаю что теперь будут скидывать) запускать рендеринг?
Читал что вроде как нету 3d max для линя. 
Переустанавливать ОС нельзя.
Есть докер контейнер для этих задач? Или может иные способы запускать рендеринг?

Comment: Боюсь, задача без переустановки ОС вряд ли решается. Докер не годится, потому что он только для линукса. Теоретически можно попробовать прокинуть gpu в виртуальную машину с виндой, но не уверен

Comment: Нашёлся некий [MaxToBlender](http://www.3dtoall.com/products/maxtoblender/). Просите экспортировать.

Comment: Если у вам Max запустится под Wine, можно будет сделать нужный докер.

Answer (score 0):

Ковыряю установку продуктов Автодеска с 2012 и не видел `3Ds Max` под Linux. `Maya.rpm` - да. Макса нет. [Официальная страница](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/System-requirements-for-Autodesk-3ds-Max-products.html) с системными требованиями:

> Operating System  Microsoft® Windows® 7 (SP1), Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 Professional operating system